# java.lang.NullPointerException error when submit the form

Tags: jsp, servlets

This is error that i got when i submitted the form. HTTP Status 500 error.

```
Jun 01, 2018 5:05:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SupplierController] in context with 
path [/jsp-projek] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at eManage.controller.SupplierController.doPost(SupplierController.java:91)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Whenever i submit a form. It says java.lang.NullPointerException error in line dao.add(supplier). I check all my input in a text box and it returns value except supplierid because i want to submit a form. How can i solve this?

```
public class SupplierController extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static String ADD = "/supplier_add.jsp";
private static String VIEW = "/supplier_view.jsp";
private static String EDIT = "/supplier_edit.jsp";
private static String LIST = "/supplier.jsp";
String forward="";
private SupplierDAO dao;
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public SupplierController() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("SupplierList")){
        forward = LIST;
        try {
            request.setAttribute("suppliers", dao.getAllSupplier());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("SupplierView")){
        forward = VIEW;
        int supplierid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("supplierid"));
        SupplierBean supplier = dao.getSupplierById(supplierid);
        request.setAttribute("supplier", supplier);
    }
    else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("SupplierDelete")){
        int supplierid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("supplierid"));
        dao.delete(supplierid);
        request.setAttribute("suppliers", dao.getAllSupplier());    
    }
    else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("SupplierEdit")){
        forward = EDIT;
        int supplierid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("supplierid"));
        SupplierBean supplier = dao.getSupplierById(supplierid);
        request.setAttribute("supplier", supplier);
    }
    else {
    forward = ADD;
    }

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    view.forward(request, response);     

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
    response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SupplierBean supplier = new SupplierBean(); 
    supplier.setSupplier_name(request.getParameter("supplier_name"));
    supplier.setSupplier_address(request.getParameter("supplier_description"));
    supplier.setSupplier_contact_num(request.getParameter("supplier_contact_num"));
    supplier.setSupplier_description(request.getParameter("supplier_description"));

    String supplierid = request.getParameter("supplier_id");
    if(supplierid == null || supplierid.isEmpty())
    {
        try {
            dao.add(supplier);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{
        supplier.setSupplier_id(Integer.parseInt(supplierid));
        try {
            dao.edit(supplier);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    forward = LIST;
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    try {
        request.setAttribute("supplier", dao.getAllSupplier());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```

}

**UPDATED

Sorry, This is my ProductDAO page. Add Method that have an error. I have set my product_id in database for autoincrements.

```
public class ProductDAO {
    static Connection currentCon = null;
    static Statement stmt=null;
    static ResultSet rs = null; 
    static PreparedStatement ps=null;

    static String  product_name, product_description, product_ori_price, product_sell_price, product_profit, product_quantity, product_supplier;
    static int product_id;

    //add new product (register)
    public void add(ProductBean bean) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{

        product_name = bean.getProduct_name();
        product_description = bean.getProduct_description();
        product_ori_price = bean.getProduct_ori_price();
        product_sell_price = bean.getProduct_sell_price();
        product_profit = bean.getProduct_profit();
        product_quantity = bean.getProduct_quantity();
        product_supplier = bean.getProduct_supplier();     

        try {
            currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            ps=currentCon.prepareStatement("insert into products(product_name, product_description, product_ori_price, product_sell_price, product_profit, product_quantity, product_supplier)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1,product_name);
            ps.setString(2,product_description);
            ps.setString(3,product_ori_price); 
            ps.setString(4,product_sell_price);
            ps.setString(5,product_profit);
            ps.setString(6,product_quantity);
            ps.setString(7,product_supplier);
            ps.execute();

            System.out.println("Your product name is " + product_name);
            System.out.println("Your product price is " + product_ori_price);

        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("failed: An Exception has occurred! " + ex);
        }

        finally {
            if (ps != null) {
                try {
                    ps.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                ps = null;
            }

            if (currentCon != null) {
                try {
                    currentCon.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                currentCon = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void edit(ProductBean bean) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        product_name = bean.getProduct_name();
        product_description = bean.getProduct_description();
        product_ori_price = bean.getProduct_ori_price();
        product_sell_price = bean.getProduct_sell_price();
        product_profit = bean.getProduct_profit();
        product_quantity = bean.getProduct_quantity();
        product_supplier = bean.getProduct_supplier();   

        String searchQuery = "UPDATE products SET product_name='" + product_name + "', product_description='" + product_description + "', product_ori_price='" + product_ori_price + "', product_sell_price= '"+ product_sell_price + "' , product_profit='" +product_profit+ "' , product_quantity='" +product_quantity+ "' , product_supplier= '"+product_supplier+"'  WHERE product_id = '" + product_id + "'";

        try {

            currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            stmt = currentCon.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(searchQuery);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void delete(int product_id) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = currentCon.prepareStatement("delete from products where product_id=?");
            // Parameters start with 1
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, product_id);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //list order 
    public List<ProductBean> getAllProduct(){

      List<ProductBean> products = new ArrayList<ProductBean>();

      try {
        currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        stmt = currentCon.createStatement();

          String sql = "select * from products";
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

          while (rs.next()) {
              ProductBean product = new ProductBean();
              product.setProduct_id(rs.getInt("product_id"));
              product.setProduct_name(rs.getString("product_name"));
              product.setProduct_ori_price(rs.getString("product__ori_price"));
              product.setProduct_sell_price(rs.getString("product_sell_price"));
              product.setProduct_profit(rs.getString("product_profit"));
              product.setProduct_quantity(rs.getString("product_quantity"));
              products.add(product);
          }

      } catch (SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }


      return products;
    }

  //get product by productid
    public ProductBean getProductById(int productid) {
        ProductBean product = new ProductBean();
        try {
            currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            ps=currentCon.prepareStatement("select * from products where product_id=?");

            ps.setInt(1, productid);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                  product.setProduct_id(rs.getInt("product_id"));
                  product.setProduct_name(rs.getString("product_name"));
                  product.setProduct_description(rs.getString("product_description"));
                  product.setProduct_ori_price(rs.getString("product__ori_price"));
                  product.setProduct_sell_price(rs.getString("product_sell_price"));
                  product.setProduct_profit(rs.getString("product_profit"));
                  product.setProduct_quantity(rs.getString("product_quantity"));
                  product.setProduct_supplier(rs.getString("product_supplier"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return product;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is `dao` defined? Please post the code for your `add` method in the dao... Also post the code for the full error.

Comment: Sorry i have edited the question. Sorry for my mistake

Comment: Thanks but that's not the full error message is it? Quite hard to see where the null pointer is coming from without the full stacktrace...

Comment: Sorry i'm still newbie in java, Can i know where the location of full stacktrace?

Comment: by stracktrace i just mean the error you get. We need to see the whole error. The error you provided there does not show us where exactly the null pointer is coming from

Comment: Sorry. That is the only whole error i got.

Comment: you only got 5 lines of error in your console?

Comment: oh sorry i forgot about the console. i just copy from the error page. I have updated the question.

Comment: hmm that error should really be showing where exactly in your ProductDAO class the nullpointer is coming from, still doesn't seem like the whole error. Also, where are you defining `dao` ?

Comment: I have updated my question. I defining my dao before public SupplierController().

Comment: private SupplierDAO dao= new SupplierDAO();

Comment: yup.. you are getting null pointer because of this line; `private SupplierDAO dao;` you need to instantiate it like deepesh comment says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SupplierDAO` is a class?? Then use atleast below code.

`private SupplierDAO dao= new SupplierDAO();`

If it is interface then use `new` on implentation class.

Comment: `private SupplierDAO dao;` //problem is here

Comment: Welcome... Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is coming from this:

```
private SupplierDAO dao;
```

Remove that line and instantiate it inside your doGet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
SupplierDAO dao = new SupplierDAO();
...
```